# iOS 14+ UNUserNotificationCenter not presenting foreground notifications as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on an iOS app and trying to handle foreground notifications using the UNUserNotificationCenter in iOS 14 and later. However, the notifications are not being presented as expected when the app is in the foreground.

Here's my code:

```
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler {
    NSLog(@"Foreground notification - appdelegate: %@", notification);

    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo;
    // Foreground
    NSLog(@"APP_PUSH from foreground %@", userInfo);

    
    if (@available(iOS 14.0, *)) {
      completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound | UNNotificationPresentationOptionBanner | UNNotificationPresentationOptionBadge);
    } else {
      completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound | UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert | UNNotificationPresentationOptionBadge);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the notifications are not showing up as expected when the app is in the foreground but it works when it is in background.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue and get the notifications to display properly in the foreground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `UNNotificationPresentationOptionList` option for iOS 14+ to allow the notification to show up while the app is in the foreground.

```
if (@available(iOS 14.0, *)) {
  completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound | UNNotificationPresentationOptionBanner | UNNotificationPresentationOptionList | UNNotificationPresentationOptionBadge);
} else {
  completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound | UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert | UNNotificationPresentationOptionBadge);
}
```